# Best AI Format/Package For Azure Custom Vision & Xamarin.Android

Tags: azure, xamarin.android, computer-vision, tensorflow-lite, onnx

I have a Custom Vision project on Azure, and a Xamarin.Android app with which I want to use the exported model. I can obviously export it in any of the formats available on Azure, which for Xamarin.Android looked like they were TensorFlow Lite & ONNX. I have been able to find very little on either of these for Xamarin.Android. I have found some stuff for Android (using Java), but with all the required NuGet packages & incomplete examples those were still too confusing to be of much help. I will definitely need help with the code later on, but right now I am trying to determine if choosing one is better than the other (I know they both do AI, I am trying to determine if one is more likely to work better with or have more help available for, since of all the topics I have ever researched I have found less on this than anything). Any suggestions?